# ValueError: View function did not return a response

Tags: python, flask, flask-testing

I try to test the edit route for my flask Application But get this error I think this error is usually because of return even though I have a return in my edit route how Can I fix this error Thanks?
error:

```
  File "/home/peg/flask-Alembic/test/test_app.py", line 59, in test_monkey_edit
    response = self.client.get('/edit/1', follow_redirects=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 762, in get
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
    response = self.run_wsgi_app(environ, buffered=buffered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 855, in run_wsgi_app
    app_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1566, in make_response
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

view.py:

```
@layout.route('/edit/<int:id>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def edit(id=None):
      user = Users.query.get_or_404(id)
      form = LoginForm(obj=user)
      if request.method=='POST':
          if form.validate_on_submit()== True:
             form.populate_obj(user)
             db.session.commit()
             flash("You have been updated the profile")
             return redirect(url_for('layout.user',page=1,sortby='normal'))

          else: #If the form does not have all fields that are required 
                return render_template('edit.html', form=form, id=id )
```

test.py:

```
def test_edit(self):
        u = Users(name='user1', email='user1@gmail.com', age=25)
        db.session.add(u)
        db.session.commit()
        data = dict(name='admin', email='adminu@gmail.com', age=28)
        db.session.commit()
        response = self.client.get('/edit/1', follow_redirects=True)
        self.assertTrue('You have been edit the profile', response.data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You test `get` request, but in your view you response only for `post`:

```
 if request.method=='POST':
          if form.validate_on_submit()== True:
             ... # form valid logic
             return redirect(url_for('layout.user',page=1,sortby='normal'))

          else: # invalid post form logic
                return render_template('edit.html', form=form, id=id )

 return render_template('home.html) # get logic
```

If you want to test `post` request you should use post function: `self.client.post(url, data)`

Example

```
def view_code():
   if request.method=='POST':
      if form.validate_on_submit()== True:
            user.name = form.user_name
            user.age = form.age
            user.email = form.email
            db.commit()
            ... # other form valid logic

def test_edit(self):
    response = self.client.post('/edit/1', data={'user_name': 'admin', age='28', email='adminu@gmail.net')
    self.assertTrue('You have been edit the profile', response.data)
```

Comment: thanx it solve the error but still doesn't cover the flash self.assertTrue('You have been edit the profile', response.data) do u know how can I do that thanx @Jimilian

Comment: @LiLi, you don't undestand how to test code. You shouldn't use db function in your test code, you should create correct `post` request with new data and post it.

Comment: @LiLi, I added some info, maybe it helps you.